# Fix 500 Internal error on reload on sveltekit

Tags: javascript, local-storage, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

svelte onreload giving me this error

on google dev console

GET http://localhost:5173/bag 500 (Internal Server Error)

on vscode

Internal server error: localStorage is not defined

i try to get and store arrays

here is my full code

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

let stored = [];

if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cat-id-from-local-storage"))) {
  stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cat-id-from-local-storage"));
}

export const storedCAtId = writable(stored);
```

i need to fix the error on reload

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` suggests there's a problem with SERVER side - you've shown client code

Comment: oh, i just need to add browser in the if condition. it is my first time using frameworks.     `if (browser && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cat-id-from-local-storage"))) {

  stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cat-id-from-local-storage"));
}`